# GCP instance group rolling update fails with error "Invalid Fingerprint"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Rolling update for an instance group fails with "Invalid Fingerprint" error message at console. Earlier rollouts had no issues but recently started seeing this error and updates are failing, even a times Instance Group section of console is going unresponsive.

Already tried : 
Creating New Image and using it in a new Template for rolling out update in instance group

Appreciate any clues or help.

Thanks

Comment: This issue is also resolved at : https://serverfault.com/questions/949836/invalid-fingerprint-instance-group-rolling-out-update-fails Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When trying to roll-out an update to my instance group with the "ROLLING RESTART/REPLACE" button, I got a “Invalid Fingerprint” error message in the Notification. This issue might also be caused by the "ROLLING UPDATE" button. (capital letters are shown at the source GCE interface)

My instance group size was set to 1 instance, and I was getting the error:

> "Invalid fingerprint"

To solve the problem, I changed the Instance Group size from 1 to 2, and then rolled the update.

After the update was done - I change the group size back to 1.

For documentation purposes, the error looks like this:

[image]

Edit the Instance Group (set number of instances) by clicking the edit button:

[image]

.. and update the number of instances:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, our Internal Compute Engine team working on the issue, The current workaround is to use the gcloud command which should also fix the issue on the Cloud Console afterwards. you can do a rolling replace using: 
gcloud beta compute instance-groups managed rolling-action replace [instance group]

You can find the details of the command [at this link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instance-groups/managed/rolling-action/). Also, you can keep an eye for complete resolution of the issue at this public issue tracker link where other users field [a defect report](https://issuetracker.google.com/123037732). I must also mention that Updating Managed Instance Group is a [beta feature](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups) as of now.